# How does the introduction of Classes in ES6 change Object creation and what about frameworks such as React that use Classes?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, reactjs

Please fill in this gap of knowledge that I have:

So as of ECMA5, Object.create() is the standard method of creating objects because the value that is passed in, is the what the created object's prototype will point to

VS

using the 'new' constructor which will make the created object's prototype point to the prototype of the constructed object. Also using new runs the constructor code in the function.

Now with the ECMA6, and the introduction of Classes, which I know is just syntactical sugar, is the standard still to use Object.create()? Im assuming Classes are just syntactical sugar for function constructors, or equivalent to using the 'new' method to create objects.

And if this is the case, why do frameworks such as React use Classes, if Object.create is more efficient?

Comment: Why do you think `Object.create` is more efficient? It was not in ES5 days either.

Comment: "*`Object.create(foo) == new Foo(Object.prototype)`*" - not at all.

Answer (score 1):

ES6 classes are not syntactic sugar, for ES5 they are transpiled into traditional prototype based constructs, but in native ES6 support it works far more efficient.

We  use classes in React to get used to this syntax, as in next few years this will be fully supported native mechanism.

For object creation itself right now you can use `Object.create` and `new`. but also object literals.
The method of having closured object factories is right now one of 'clean-code-recommended' - benefits of better control of coupling, local('private') variables and methods.

Comment: So just to clarify: Object factories are delegated to Classes now, and just use object literals if we no need for inheritance, correct? So object.create() is almost deprecated now

Comment: I never sad that either of these methods it deprecated. Use `closures` to produce most of objects as long as it does not come to performance. In this case `Object.create` is AFAIK fastest. Nevertheless sometimes we may need classic constructor combined with performance  - use `new`

Answer (score 0):

As you said, `class`es just are syntactic sugar for constructors. They don't change the picture at all. Sometimes you will want to use `new`, sometimes you will want to use `Object.create`, they just do different things:

> Also using new runs the constructor code in the function

And React needs this, so they use constructors.